# How to shuffle groups of rows of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shuffle

Let's assume I have a dataframe df:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,4))

print(df)

     0   1   2   3
0   71  64  84  20
1   48  60  83  61
2   48  78  71  46
3   65  88  66  77
4   71  22  42  58
5   66  76  64  80
6   67  28  74  87
7   32  90  55  78
8   80  42  52  14
9   54  76  73  17
10  32  89  42  36
11  85  78  61  12
```

How do I shuffle the rows of df three-by-three, i.e., how do I randomly shuffle the first three rows (0, 1, 2) with either the second (3, 4, 5), third (6, 7, 8) or fourth (9, 10, 11) group? This could be a possible outcome:

```
print(df)

     0   1   2   3
3   65  88  66  77
4   71  22  42  58
5   66  76  64  80
9   54  76  73  17
10  32  89  42  36
11  85  78  61  12
6   67  28  74  87
7   32  90  55  78
8   80  42  52  14
0   71  64  84  20
1   48  60  83  61
2   48  78  71  46
```

Thus, the new order has the second group of `3` rows from original dataframe, then the last one, then the third one and finally the first group.

Comment: By shuffle, you do you mean swap `0` with `3`, `1` with `4`, `2` with `5` and so on?

Comment: Nope, swap (0,1,2) randomly with (3,4,5), (6,7,8) or (9,10,11).

Comment: And do this for the all the packs of `3 rows`?

Comment: Yep, so shuffle randomly group 1 with either group 2, 3, or 4, for which every group contains 3 rows. I'll make an edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Still not 100% sure what exactly you mean - are you wanting to shuffle rows but in groups of 3 (each group retains ordering but shifts around - or just two groups swap places etc...). Could you provide example output? That'd help clarify your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reshape into a `3D` array splitting the first axis into two with the latter one of length `3` corresponding to the group length and then use [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) for such a groupwise in-place shuffle along the first axis, which being of length as the number of groups holds those groups and thus achieves our desired result, like so -

```
np.random.shuffle(df.values.reshape(-1,3,df.shape[1]))
```

**Explanation**

To give it a bit of explanation, let's use `np.random.permutation` to generate those random indices along the first axis and then index into the `3D` array version.

1] Input df :

```
In [199]: df
Out[199]: 
     0   1   2   3
0   71  64  84  20
1   48  60  83  61
2   48  78  71  46
3   65  88  66  77
4   71  22  42  58
5   66  76  64  80
6   67  28  74  87
7   32  90  55  78
8   80  42  52  14
9   54  76  73  17
10  32  89  42  36
11  85  78  61  12
```

2] Get `3D` array version :

```
In [200]: arr_3D = df.values.reshape(-1,3,df.shape[1])

In [201]: arr_3D
Out[201]: 
array([[[71, 64, 84, 20],
        [48, 60, 83, 61],
        [48, 78, 71, 46]],

       [[65, 88, 66, 77],
        [71, 22, 42, 58],
        [66, 76, 64, 80]],

       [[67, 28, 74, 87],
        [32, 90, 55, 78],
        [80, 42, 52, 14]],

       [[54, 76, 73, 17],
        [32, 89, 42, 36],
        [85, 78, 61, 12]]])
```

3] Get shuffling indices and index into the first axis of `3D` version :

```
In [202]: shuffle_idx = np.random.permutation(arr_3D.shape[0])

In [203]: shuffle_idx
Out[203]: array([0, 3, 1, 2])

In [204]: arr_3D[shuffle_idx]
Out[204]: 
array([[[71, 64, 84, 20],
        [48, 60, 83, 61],
        [48, 78, 71, 46]],

       [[54, 76, 73, 17],
        [32, 89, 42, 36],
        [85, 78, 61, 12]],

       [[65, 88, 66, 77],
        [71, 22, 42, 58],
        [66, 76, 64, 80]],

       [[67, 28, 74, 87],
        [32, 90, 55, 78],
        [80, 42, 52, 14]]])
```

Then, we are assigning these values back to input dataframe.

With `np.random.shuffle`, we are just doing everything in-place and hiding away the work needed to explicitly generate shuffling indices and assigning back.

**Sample run -**

```
In [181]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(11,99,(12,4)))

In [182]: df
Out[182]: 
     0   1   2   3
0   82  49  80  20
1   19  97  74  81
2   62  20  97  19
3   36  31  14  41
4   27  86  28  58
5   38  68  24  83
6   85  11  25  88
7   21  31  53  19
8   38  45  14  72
9   74  63  40  94
10  69  85  53  81
11  97  96  28  29

In [183]: np.random.shuffle(df.values.reshape(-1,3,df.shape[1]))

In [184]: df
Out[184]: 
     0   1   2   3
0   85  11  25  88
1   21  31  53  19
2   38  45  14  72
3   82  49  80  20
4   19  97  74  81
5   62  20  97  19
6   36  31  14  41
7   27  86  28  58
8   38  68  24  83
9   74  63  40  94
10  69  85  53  81
11  97  96  28  29
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar solution to @Divakar, probably simpler as I directly shuffle the index of the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(0, 12)]*4).T
len_group = 3

index_list = np.array(df.index)
np.random.shuffle(np.reshape(index_list, (-1, len_group)))

shuffled_df = df.loc[index_list, :]
```

Sample output:

```
shuffled_df
    Out[82]: 
     0   1   2   3
9    9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10
11  11  11  11  11
3    3   3   3   3
4    4   4   4   4
5    5   5   5   5
0    0   0   0   0
1    1   1   1   1
2    2   2   2   2
6    6   6   6   6
7    7   7   7   7
8    8   8   8   8
```

Comment: Nice one! I am guessing the difference would be indexing with `.loc`, which compared to NumPy's in-place edit might not be the most performant one and also `loc` is making a copy there.

Comment: I tried this approach, but for some reason the last line in your code does not seem to work, only the index is shuffled, the values remain... Any ideas what the reason might be for this?

Comment: Not really...I have updated my example so that it is easier to see that values are swapped as well. Are you sure yours it some kind of special case (e.g. all values being identical or with cyclical repetitions?)

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the example in my answer?

Comment: Fixed, made us of it in a loop, at second step it only changed the index, not the values anymore. Had to include `index_list = np.array(df.index)` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, i think the two possible issues are that: np.random.shuffle operates in-place  and that indexes are mutable

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the same as the other two answers, but using integer division to create a group column.

```
nrows_df = len(df)
nrows_group = 3

shuffled = (
    df
    .assign(group_var=df.index // nrows_group)
    .set_index("group_var")
    .loc[np.random.permutation(nrows_df / nrows_group)]
)
```